# Nine patch background destroys layout

Tags: android, nine-patch

I created 4x4 `GridLayout` and it works fine. Then I added nine-patch background and then only single incomplete row is displayed in a device while the Android Studio's designer shows expected view. Mobile phones do not work but tablets do.  Where is the problem?

It works on a tablet:

[image: Tablet]

It does not work on a phone:

[image: Mobile]

It does work on a phone without nine patch:

[image: No background]

Nine patch picture:

[image: Nine patch file]

Comment: Any reason why you didn't put the fill area in the 9patch?1

Comment: What do you mean? Strechable area marks like described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch. Yes, there are there.

Comment: The 9-patch image you provided above does not match the one in the phone layout, as you can see the arc line is stretched. It could be that you are not properly created the 9-patch or the patch image is just to large for the phone density.

Comment: A designer sent me new set of images and it works now. It is strange why nine-patch file can make button so tall. He used https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html this time.